# sortBy not sorting items in directive table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="sortBy">
  <option value="createdAt"><strong>Date</strong></option>
  <option value="ProgressStateNumber"><strong>Progress</strong></option>
  <option value="adminUsername"><strong>adminUsername</strong></option>
</select>

<tbody>
  <tr
    reportrowgroup
      ng-repeat="report in reportTree track by $index | orderBy: sortBy"
      report="report"
    >
```

**Directive:**

```
  .directive('reportrowgroup', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template:
        '<td>{{report.createdAt | date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"}}</td>'+
        'MORE HTML'
        scope: {
            report: '='
        },
        controller: function() {
        },
        link: function(scope,elem,attr,ctrl) {
      }
        }
    }
})
```

Everything works, except the table doesn't sort by `createdAt` when I select `createdAt` in `select`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: could you reproduce the problem with fiddle/plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reportrowgroup` directive is creating a new `scope` and therefore missing the reference to the same `sortBy` variable. Try wrapping the `sortyBy` in an object.

```
<!-- markup -->
<select class="form-control" ng-model="input.sortBy">

// Code
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.input = {
    sortBy: 'default-value-goes-here'
  };
});
```

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MmjuaLfvVnOQb0Ngz0dI?p=preview

Comment: Should I define that object in the controller or something like that? And how to use it in the directive?

Comment: That's optional -- angular expressions will generate parent objects if it detects a dot. Defining it explicitly in your controller does make your code cleaner to read tho.

Comment: I copied your code and also wrote `ng-repeat="report in reportTree track by $index | orderBy: input.sortBy`. Not working yet.

Comment: Also note that the are some `<strong>` markings in the `select > option` elements.

Comment: Hey, it worked, even without having `sortBy` as an object. The issue was having `track by $index` in the middle rather than at the end of the `ng-repeat`. Damn! Anyway, thanks a lot for the Plunkr.